# Iframe 100% full width bootstrap3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I found a good contact page that I want reproduce, see [this link](http://www.pasticceriaicapricci.it/) at Contatti section.

I'm using Initializr with Twitter Bootstrap3.

Here is HTML/css/js structure for Contact Section, I've a gmaps iframe (id="map") inside iframeWrapper placed with position:relative, iframeBlock is a full width/height panel with opacity = 0.7 to overshadow iframe, iframeCont with two panel with some contact link and btn-map and btn-cont to switch between active (no opacity and possibility to make the scroll and to use zoom buttons ) and inactive iframe.
I set position:absolute for all other element inside a iframeWrapper.

```js
$('#btn-map').click(function(){
    $('#iframeBlock').hide();
    $('#iframeCont').hide();
    $('#btn-map').css('display','none');
    $('#btn-cont').css('display','block');
});

$('#btn-cont').click(function(){
    $('#iframeBlock').show();
    $('#iframeCont').show();
    $('#btn-map').css('display','block');
    $('#btn-cont').css('display','none');       
});
```

```css
#cont{
   width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
}
#map{
   z-index:5;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
#iframeWrapper{
  position: relative;
}
#iframeBlock{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity:0.7;
  background: #000;
  z-index: 6;
  text-align:center;
}
#iframeCont{
  position: absolute;
  top:20%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 7;
  text-align:center;
}
.cont-element{
  background: #0b5394;
  color:#FFF;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 3%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

#btn-map{
  position: absolute;
  top:70%;
  left:25%;
  z-index: 7;
  opacity: 1;
  background: #cc0000;
  color: #FFF;
  border-color: #FFF;
  display:block;
}
#btn-cont{
  position: absolute;
  top:70%;
  left:30%;
  z-index: 7;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #000;
  border-color: #cc0000;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
 <!-- Contatti Section -->
      <section id="cont" class="cont-section">
          <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row-fluid">
                <div id="iframeWrapper">

                   <iframe id="map" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2786.232975915266!2d8.878734115818997!3d45.70636282527264!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x478688abc9247355%3A0x59d85ca1774dc65a!2sASD+Pallacanestro+Lonate+Ceppino!5e0!3m2!1sit!2sit!4v1445187794194" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

                   <div id="iframeBlock">

                   </div>

                   <div id="iframeCont">
                    
                      <div class="row">
                       <div class="col-xs-2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-8 cont-element">
                          <i class="fa fa-mobile"></i> </br> <a href:"tel:xxxxxxxx">xxxxxxxx</a> <span>Giovanni</span>    
                        </div>
                         <div class="col-xs-2">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                       
                      <div class="row">
                       <div class="col-xs-2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-8 cont-element">
                           <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> </br> <a href="mailto:xxxxxxxx@gmail.com">xxxxxxxx@gmail.com</a> 
                        </div>
                         <div class="col-xs-2">
                        </div>
                      </div>

                     </div>
                        
                                <button id="btn-map" class="btn btn-info btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-map-o"></i> <strong>Visualizza Mappa</strong></button>
                                <button id="btn-cont" class="btn btn-info btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> <strong>Contattaci</strong></button>

                  </div>
 
                </div>   
              </div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

Everything works but I have a padding of 15px around iframeWrapper due to container-fluid and then see two white borders on the left and right side.

I tried to reset the padding for the container-fluid to zero, but It displays a horizontal scroll bar and it is as if the content is outside the viewport.

[Image that show contact section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgvMS.jpg)

Could you help me? Thanks

Comment: Remove the `margin` from `body` ?

Comment: body {margin:0} ( bootstrap.min.css rule), if I remove this horizontal scroll bar appears!

Comment: try adding `overflow: visible;` @Filippo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

analyzing the code with Google Chrome Developers Tool, I found that two rows exceed viewport width. (For example, if viewport width is 380px, the row width is 410px), so I write this CSS rule:

```
#iframeCont .row{
  width: 100%;
}
```

which refers just to the two rows, and now I have no more white space around my iframe.

But for me is a bad solution! I probably poorly designed html structure!